# Move the page border towards the right in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, border

By default, if I add a border to my page, it creates the border line after some 5 pts from the leftmost of the page. Is there any way that I can increase this size? I want the left border to be created after 10 pts. Is there a way to achieve this Word 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

In the Page Layout tab, in the Page Background tab click on borders

In the Page Border tab, click options (near the cancel button)

In here, you can change it (assuming you've applied the border to the whole document and not just some text), but you're limited here by how much you can increase it by, however, to increase it by a small amount like 5pts you should be fine.